# Is it possible to unambiguously identify a substance with a rapid test?

Tags: analytical-chemistry

I've seen a documentary about the narcotics control at the Jorge Chávez International Airport in Peru. The officers used a rapid test to identify cocaine. They put a cotton swab into the substance. The test was positive if it turned turquoise.

How does the test work? Is it really possible to unambiguously identify a substance by the color change? How can any known or even yet unknown substance be ruled out to react in the same way?

Comment: I don't know how advanced forensic science is. But to me, a more likely scenario is that this is just a quick test to determine whether somebody should be reeled in for further questioning/investigation. It would need to be combined with other evidence to be conclusive.

Comment: They were arrested and handcuffed on the spot (and questioned further). The alleged cocaine was weighed exactly to the gram. The potential prison sentence was based on the weight. I found that strange, too, since even if the test was right, the drug could have been diluted.

Comment: What documentary was that?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Don't know for sure (and didn't even know back then), but it might have been one of those: https://www.natgeotv.com/za/shows/natgeo/airport-security-peru